# Disable or modify functions of physical buttons throughout phone

Tags: android

I want to disable or modify the functions of the physical buttons on my phone, I understand root might be required. I found many other SO questions on how to do this in only one application but I would like to do this throughout the entire phone when a physical button is pressed. Is this possible? Perhaps by using a broadcast receiver or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Not really. If your device has a CAMERA button, and the foreground activity does not consume a CAMERA button click, that will result in an ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON broadcast. If your app contains a home screen, that screen can get control when the user presses the HOME button, if they chose your home screen to be their default home screen.

Beyond that, nothing else is possible, except by modifying the OS and building your own firmware.